# Remove rows based on a Pandas groupby() result

Tags: python, pandas

I want to remove a subset of rows from a Pandas `DataFrame` based on a `groupby()` inspection.

The primary `DataFrame`:

```
>>> df
   name  day       fruit  foobar
0   Tim    1       Apple       0
1   Tim    1       Apple       1
2   Tim    2       Apple       2
3  Anna    1      Banana       3
4  Anna    1  Strawberry       4
5   Bob    1  Strawberry       5
6   Bob    2       Apple       6
7   Bob    2        Kiwi       7
```

I group this by `name` and `fruit` and filter by `foobar > 5`.

```
g = df.groupby(['name', 'fruit']).agg(sum)
g = g[(g.foobar > 5)]
```

Result is

```
>>> g
name fruit
Bob  Apple    2       6
     Kiwi     2       7
```

Now I want to remove the related rows from `df` so that the primary `DataFrame` looks like this at the end:

```
>>> df
   name  day       fruit  foobar
0   Tim    1       Apple       0
1   Tim    1       Apple       1
2   Tim    2       Apple       2
3  Anna    1      Banana       3
4  Anna    1  Strawberry       4
5   Bob    1  Strawberry       5
```

It does not matter for me if `name` and `fruit` is the index or just a usual column.

Is this what is called a *left outer join*?

This is the full code to create the sample data.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'name': ['Tim', 'Tim', 'Tim', 'Anna', 'Anna', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Bob'],
        'day': [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
        'fruit': ['Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Strawberry',
                  'Strawberry', 'Apple', 'Kiwi'],
        'foobar': range(8),
}

# That is the initial DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

g = df.groupby(['name', 'day']).agg(sum)
g = g[(g.foobar > 5)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for repeat aggregated values per groups, so possible filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with inverted mask `>` to `<=`:

```
df = df[df.groupby(['name', 'fruit']).foobar.transform(sum) <= 5]
print (df)
   name  day       fruit  foobar
0   Tim    1       Apple       0
1   Tim    1       Apple       1
2   Tim    2       Apple       2
3  Anna    1      Banana       3
4  Anna    1  Strawberry       4
5   Bob    1  Strawberry       5
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I see the difference between `.transform(sum)` and `.agg(sum)` while testing it with this MWE. But I do not get into the logic behind it. How do I decide when to use which one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is an elegant solution. Based on [this tutorial](https://thispointer.com/python-pandas-how-to-drop-rows-in-dataframe-by-conditions-on-column-values/).

Booth `DataFrame` need to have the same index.

```
df.set_index(['name', 'fruit'])
```

After that simple [`drop()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) by index..

```
df = df.drop(g.indes)
```